# VBA - how does "Long" work in VBA - playing with owerflow

Tags: vba, excel, integer-overflow

So I know that in Excel VBA, `Long` range is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

I am experimenting with file size handling and overflow right now and I am wondering what exactly happens when I overflow the range.

So in the code I ask for a file size in bytes with the `FileLen` function.

If the file is larger than `2,147,483,647 bytes`, the messages I will get will be a negative value. I think this is because the function will start using the negative values since it ran out of positive ones.

The interesting thing was when I ran the function on some bigger files: 
one of them was `4 294 552 366 bytes` and the other is `4 298 779 628 bytes`
for one I got the expected negative value and for the other I got a positive value again.

Results:
4 043 308 965 bytes - `-251658331`
4 294 552 366 bytes - `-414930`
4 298 779 628 bytes - `3812332`

I have tried to do some math with this, but I can not figure out its logic.
Could someone explain what happens in the background and why do I get these results?

Comment: It might be it exceeds 4 295 000 000 bytes, have you tried saving the file in binary format?

Comment: @Linga - how can I do that? I checked the size in properties, it says `Size: 3,99 GB (4 294 552 366 bytes)` `Size on disk: 3,99 GB (4 294 553 600 bytes)`

Comment: You need to do save as & choose **save as type** as **Excel Binary format** which will reduce the size of the file.

Comment: @Linga This is a .zip file that I am experimenting with

Comment: It doesn't matter the Macro your trying with excel file right? Then do save as the file in binary format, hope this will help you :)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? (If it's 64 bit try using [**`LongLong`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251528.aspx): `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`)

Comment: @paulbica - I am using 32 bit version unfortunately. But I find it a nice idea and this could help lots of people facing a similar problem. You can add your comment (with some more details) as an answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a 7GB file for testing, here is what I get:
The actual file size is 7017693184 Bytes, =

```
110100010010010011000000000000000
```

(33 digits in a 64-bit Integer, imagine more zeros to the left to fill up 64 digits).
FileLen obviously just truncates the value and takes the lower 32 bits.
It returns -1572241408 Bytes for the file which indeed is

```
 10100010010010011000000000000000
```

=almost the same, just one 1 cut off at the beginning.
Since now in this 32-bit Integer the MSB (most significant bit, ie. the left-most '1') is set, this becomes a negative number (if you want to know more about this, [read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement))
This is rather odd, the method should better throw an overflow error.

***Solution***:
It seems the `FileSystemObject` can handle large files:

```
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.Getfile(..filename..)
MsgBox _
    f.Size & " Byte" & _
    vbCrLf & f.Size / 1024 & " KB" & _
    vbCrLf & f.Size / 1024 / 1024 & " MB"
```